# Restore database from pg_dump

Tags: database, postgresql, psql, pg-dump

I had non-empty db and made backup it by:

`pg_dump myBase > backup.sql`

Then I must to delete db and now I am trying to restore it from backup.sql. So first I create database by:

`create database myBase`

grant privileges from `psql`

`grant all privileges on database "myBase" to myUser`

and then trying to recover from pg_dump by:

`pg_dump myBase < backup.sql`

And I didn't get any errors, but when I check tables by `\dt` it's totally empty.
I have also tried restoring with:

`psql -h localhost -d myBase-U myUser-f backup.sql` (no error, but no tables too)

`psql myBase < backup.sql` (like above)

I have a little expieriences with dbs so I assume it should be something obvious for more experienced user.

Comment: how do you check if the dp is empty? `psql myBase -c "\dt"`?..

Comment: `\dt` shows tables in db, and I have "no relations found"

Comment: so before you drop db you have a list and after restoring same command shows no relations found?..

Comment: Yes, before drop "\dt" shows list of tables, and after restore I have "no relations found".

Comment: cant reproduce. see the answer.  no idea why you have no errors and no relations. I mean many possible failure points, but can't see how to guess

Comment: is backup.sql populated with the expected tables/data?

Comment: @JGH It has abaout 1500 lines, so I am not sure in 100% everything is ok, but I check couple spots and looks fine, with my tables, columns and data. But I didn't use any validator, is there any?

Comment: just in case `psql -h localhost -d myBase-U myUser -f backup.sql -X` does not change anything?..

Comment: nope, it doesn't

Answer (score 1):

Can't reproduce the issue:

```
postgres=# create database so;
CREATE DATABASE
postgres=# \c so
You are now connected to database "so" as user "postgres".
so=# create table so(i int);
CREATE TABLE
so=# insert into so values (1);
INSERT 0 1
so=# \! pg_dump so > /tmp/so.sql
so=# \c postgres
You are now connected to database "postgres" as user "postgres".
postgres=# drop database so;
DROP DATABASE
postgres=# create database so;
CREATE DATABASE
postgres=# \c so
You are now connected to database "so" as user "postgres".
so=# \dt
No relations found.
so=# \! psql so -f /tmp/so.sql
SET
SET
SET
SET
SET
SET
CREATE EXTENSION
COMMENT
SET
SET
SET
CREATE TABLE
ALTER TABLE
REVOKE
REVOKE
GRANT
GRANT
so=# \dt
        List of relations
 Schema | Name | Type  |  Owner
--------+------+-------+----------
 public | so   | table | postgres
(1 row)
```

Comment: I follow your instructions and example for "SO" work without problems, but my case still doesn't work. What I see is difference on restoring db line "-f /tmp/so.sql". You example produces couple lines of what is currently happening, and mine not even one. Maybe my dump is broken?

Comment: if you have an error in statements it will give error to stdout... of course you can add `\o some_file` to the first line of sql script and then psql will send all output to some_file, but you said you did not modify it?.. neither you used `-o` switch - right?..

Comment: BTW dump can't be broken. It works on Windows.I create new database, user, grant privileges, restore data and locally it works. So it just doesn't work on linux for some reason

Answer (score 0):

Got the same problem, found the solution here: [Unable to restore psql database from pg_dump with a different username](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52571599/unable-to-restore-psql-database-from-pg-dump-with-a-different-username)

> pg_dump dbname -O -x > backupname.sql
>
> -O   <-- No owner
>            Do not output commands to set ownership of objects to match the original database
>
> -x   <-- No privileges
>            Prevent dumping of access privileges (grant/revoke commands)